# What does the keyword 'unit' before a package name do?

Tags: raku

In the following code;

```
unit module Fancy::Calculator;
```

what does 'unit' actually do?  I know that the scope for the definition of the module becomes the file its declared in - as opposed to;

```
module Fancy::Calculator {
    # module definition statements here
}
```

where the scope is obviously defined by the curlies but I can't see anything in the documentation that definitively states that that is **all** that it does and I'd be a little surprised if that's all that it did.  Secondarily, after making such a declaration, can one declare `unit class Whatever` (class, module, whatever) half way down and call an end to the previous scope definition?

Comment: That is all it does, please add a bug report, or create a Pull Request for https://github.com/perl6/doc

Comment: Marty, did you ever make a bug report about that? The feature is still undocumented, so I'd like to make sure it's on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a commenter (thanks Brad), it appears that is all it does.  As for starting a second Module within the same file - you can't use unit module again - that produces;

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/user/Fancy/Calculator.pm6
Too late for unit-scoped module definition;
Please use the block form.
```

...but as the message says, you can use the block form but whatever you declare is within the unit module namespace - Fancy::Calculator in this case.  So these;

```
unit module Fancy::Calculator;

# The following available to the module user as Fancy::Calculator::Adder
class Adder {
    method add { "Hi... I am a method who can add" }
}

# Starting definition of new module but its within Fancy::Calculator namespace
module Minus {

    # Following available to the module user as Fancy::Calculator::Minus::Subber
    class Subber {
        method subtract { "Hi... I am a method who can subtract" }
    }

    # unless you add "is export" in which case its available by its short name
    class Multiplyer is export {
        method times { "Hi... I am a method who can multiply" }
    }

    sub divide() is export { "Hi... I am a sub who can divide" }
}
```

are accessed like this;

```
# In main
use Fancy::Calculator;

my $fca = Fancy::Calculator::Adder.new;
say $fca.add;              # Hi... I am a method who can add
my $fcms = Fancy::Calculator::Minus::Subber.new;
say $fcms.subtract;        # Hi... I am a method who can subtract
my $mul = Multiplyer.new;
say $mul.times;            # Hi... I am a sub who can multiply
say divide();              # Hi... I am a sub who can divide
```